Rewards not increasing in Actor-Critic model in a custom environment
I am trying to implement an Actor-Critic Deep Reinforcement Learning model to predict training intensities for clients with different processing powers in a distributed machine learning setup (Federated Learning). So I iterate over certain amount of episodes and each episode has a number of rounds. The actor-critic model has to predict the training intensities for a fixed set of client in each round.
My state is a list of training times for each client, for the last h number of rounds (saving historical information for the last h rounds). So basically the state dimension is num_clients*h.
My actions are the training intensities for each client. So action dimension is num_clients.
My actor-critic networks are given as follows -
num_clients = 5
h = 4
state_dimension = num_clients*h
action_dimension = num_clients

class PolicyNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_dimension, action_dimension):
        super(PolicyNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(state_dimension, 128)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(128, action_dimension)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.input_layer(x))
        action_probs = F.softmax(self.output_layer(x), dim=1)
        return action_probs

class StateValueNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_dimension):
        super(StateValueNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.input_layer = nn.Linear(state_dimension, 128)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(128, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.input_layer(x))
        state_value = self.output_layer(x)
        return state_value

Each client has different processing power, described by its cpu cycles per data sample and cpu frequency. Based on this, its training time is calculated. I want to train the actor network to find the training intensities for each client such that the maximum difference between client training times is reduced. (so that it is balanced and there is no waiting delay)
So my reward=-(Max difference of training times)
Training the actor and critic is done by using a replay buffer.
Initially for each episode, the state is empty and for each round it is updated. Once h rounds are over, then the actor-critic starts to predict the policy.
I used 5 clients for my implementation.
The main logic and training of actor-critic is given as follows -
#Defining parameters
num_episodes = 3
num_rounds=15
total_training_intensity=15
BATCH_SIZE = 10
cpu_cycles = torch.rand(5) * (30 - 10) + 10
size_data_sample = 4
cpu_freq = torch.rand(5) * (1.0 - 0.1) + 0.1

#Define replay buffer
class ReplayBuffer:
    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.buffer = deque(maxlen=capacity)

    def push(self, state, action, reward, next_state):
        self.buffer.append(Experience(state, action, reward, next_state))

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        return random.sample(self.buffer, batch_size)

#MAIN LOGIC
for episode in range(num_episodes):
    episode_reward = 0

    for rnd in range(num_rounds):
        if rnd==0:
            #Initially set state to all zero
            state = deque()
        flattened_state = [item for sublist in state for item in sublist]
        state_tensor = torch.tensor(flattened_state, dtype=torch.float32)
        #Normalize state
        state_tensor = (state_tensor - state_tensor.mean()) / (state_tensor.std() + 1e-10)
        state_tensor = state_tensor.view(-1)

        if(len(state)!=h):
            #Initiate same training intensity for clients for the first 3 rounds
            intensities = [round(float(total_training_intensity)/float(num_clients)) for _ in range(num_clients)]
        else:
            #Get training intensities from policy network for remaining rounds
            actions,_ = select_action(policy_network, state_tensor)
            intensities = [round(i * total_training_intensity) if round(i * total_training_intensity) != 0 else 1 for i in actions]

        print('Local training intensities: ',intensities)

        client_training_time = []
        for i in range(num_clients):
            client_training_time.append((intensities[i]*cpu_cycles[i]*size_data_sample)/(cpu_freq[i]*1e3))     #Get client training time

        #Define new state
        if(len(state)==h):
            state.popleft()
        state.append(client_training_time)
        #Normalize new state to add in the replay buffer
        flattened_new_state = [item for sublist in state for item in sublist]
        new_state_tensor = torch.tensor(flattened_new_state, dtype=torch.float32)
        new_state_tensor = (new_state_tensor - new_state_tensor.mean()) / (new_state_tensor.std() + 1e-10)
        new_state_tensor = new_state_tensor.view(-1)

        #Get reward
        normal_list = [float(tensor_item) for tensor_item in client_training_time]
        reward = -(max(normal_list) - min(normal_list))
        episode_reward += reward

        # Store transition tuple into experience replay buffer
        if(rnd>=h):
          #Add to buffer
           replay_buffer.push(state_tensor.tolist(),actions,reward,new_state_tensor.tolist())

    # Train on a batch of experiences
    if len(replay_buffer) >= BATCH_SIZE:
      for i in range(3):
        experiences = replay_buffer.sample(BATCH_SIZE)
        batch = Experience(*zip(*experiences))
        for i in range(3):
          state_batch = torch.FloatTensor(batch.state).to(DEVICE)
          action_batch = torch.LongTensor(batch.action).unsqueeze(1).to(DEVICE)
          reward_batch = torch.FloatTensor(batch.reward).unsqueeze(1).to(DEVICE)
          next_state_batch = torch.FloatTensor(batch.next_state).to(DEVICE)

          # Compute value loss
          current_values = stateval_network(state_batch)
          next_values = stateval_network(next_state_batch)
          expected_values = reward_batch + DISCOUNT_FACTOR * next_values
          value_loss = F.mse_loss(current_values, expected_values.detach())

          # Compute policy loss
          advantage = expected_values.detach() - current_values.detach()
          action_probs = policy_network(state_batch)
          policy_loss = -(torch.log(action_probs) * advantage).mean()

          # Update networks
          stateval_optimizer.zero_grad()
          value_loss.backward()
          stateval_optimizer.step()

          policy_optimizer.zero_grad()
          policy_loss.backward()
          policy_optimizer.step()

The actor-critic model works on a virtual environment like Cartpole, and the rewards graph increases as expected. But when I modified it to add my new environment definition, the rewards graph does not increase and the actor seems to be predicting random actions. I have a feeling that there is something wrong with the training part or the buffer logic. What could be the issue?
